# How to execute native query and get feedback?

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate, jdbc

**How to execute native query (create table)** in java and also in return get information about is operation was successfull or not. Every method i did try always work the same. Query is working but i am getting errors about "how really bad that query was" but as i said it works.

```
try{
      session.createNativeQuery("create table test (id number)").getResultList()
}
catch(Exception e){
    // I am getting error "Could not extract result set metadata"
    // Is there any way to execute getResultList() only if operation was select?
}
```

Summarizing, I need execute CRUD.
1. If "select" was executed i need resultList.
2. If "create" i don't want to execute getResultSet()
3. If "insert" was executed i need information about numbers of row affected.
etc... ... ...
And most important i always need information about eventual errors! If query had missing syntax or something i always need to get that information.

*Guys can someone help me? I am fighting with this from several days...*

Comment: We can't comment on the code and the errors that you didn't post. Your attempt with createNativeQuery doesn't work because you create a query, but never execute it. Your  attempt with prepareStatement doesn't do what you want because... you ignore what it returns, and are not following the instructions in the javadoc in order to get the result: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#execute--. Using `executeUpdate()` would be simpler, but you also need to not ignore the result. Read the javadoc.

Comment: createNativeQuery() is executed. I have everything in my database after that line. Is executed but this never ever return any feedback for me.

Comment: No it's not. Not in the code you posted. If your actual code is different, and you want us to explain what problem your actual code has and how to fix it, then post your actual code.

Comment: You was right, sorry that was bad example... But still that "errors" about metadata disturb me... I don't want to get resultSet of objects when i am executing query like "create"

Comment: The don't. getResultList() is for ... getting a result list from a SELECT query. You don't want to do that. Use executeUpdate().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple example using Native Query. You can determine the result of query from the `affected rows` value.

```
        EntityTransaction entityTransaction;
        EntityManager entityManager;

        try
        {
            entityTransaction = entityManager.getTransaction();

            entityTransaction.begin();

            // rowsUpdated - The number of "affected rows".
            int rowsUpdated = entityManager.createNativeQuery("create table test (id nubmer)").executeUpdate();

            entityTransaction.commit();
        }
        catch (HibernateException | IllegalStateException e)
        {
            // handle exceptions

            if (entityTransaction != null && entityTransaction.isActive())
            {
                entityTransaction.rollback();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Very thanks but i have question about that last if. When exactly the compiler will get into that if?

Comment: This was very simple example, doing catch all exception which is not great. I replaced with specific exceptions. The last `if` check is to avoid the NullPointerException if `entityTransaction` is `null` and making sure that transaction is active beofore rolling back the transaction. In this case, `if` will be executed when `HibernateException` or `IllegalStateException` thrown by the code within `try` block.